# How can I make A stopwatch in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[Expected ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjChT.png)
I want to make it

```
  child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        DateTime.now()
                            .toLocal()
                            .toString()
                            .split('.')[0], // Display current date and time
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        '00:00:00',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

This is my code. I am fully new in flutter. I would be gratefull if you suggest me the right way to design the ui. Also I can't add the animation

Comment: You'll need to use shadows with varying offsets (according to the animation controller).

Answer (score 0):

I Have Created a `Single class` **Stopwatch** App for you in the given snippets.
[image]

```
class MyStopwatch extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStopwatch({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStopwatch> createState() => _MyStopwatchState();
}

class _MyStopwatchState extends State<MyStopwatch> {
  final Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  late Duration _elapsedTime;
  late String _elapsedTimeString;
  late Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _elapsedTime = Duration.zero;
    _elapsedTimeString = _formatElapsedTime(_elapsedTime);

    // Create a timer that runs a callback every 100 milliseconds to update UI
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        // Update elapsed time only if the stopwatch is running
        if (_stopwatch.isRunning) {
          _updateElapsedTime();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Start/Stop button callback
  void _startStopwatch() {
    if (!_stopwatch.isRunning) {
      // Start the stopwatch and update elapsed time
      _stopwatch.start();
      _updateElapsedTime();
    } else {
      // Stop the stopwatch
      _stopwatch.stop();
    }
  }

  // Reset button callback
  void _resetStopwatch() {
    // Reset the stopwatch to zero and update elapsed time
    _stopwatch.reset();
    _updateElapsedTime();
  }

  // Update elapsed time and formatted time string
  void _updateElapsedTime() {
    setState(() {
      _elapsedTime = _stopwatch.elapsed;
      _elapsedTimeString = _formatElapsedTime(_elapsedTime);
    });
  }

  // Format a Duration into a string (MM:SS.SS)
  String _formatElapsedTime(Duration time) {
    return '${time.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(time.inSeconds.remainder(60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}.${(time.inMilliseconds % 1000 ~/ 100).toString()}';
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Stopwatch App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Display elapsed time
            Text(
              _elapsedTimeString,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            // Start/Stop and Reset buttons
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _startStopwatch,
                  child: Text(_stopwatch.isRunning ? 'Stop' : 'Start'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _resetStopwatch,
                  child: const Text('Reset'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Some Important things you must know about. it will help you modify the
> Code according to your needs.

- The `_stopwatch` variable is an instance of the `Stopwatch` class, which is used to measure elapsed time.
- `_elapsedTime` represents the current elapsed time, and `_elapsedTimeString` is a formatted string for displaying the elapsed time in the user interface.
- The `timer` is a periodic timer that updates the UI every **100 milliseconds** (to show the elapsed time).